# Share jpeg image from my app

Tags: android, image, share, whatsapp

I have problems sharing an image from my folder drawable.
On Whatsapp works fine, but if I try to share on Line, I get a prompt error from them. If i try to share by email, the file is attached without extension. 
Anyone can help me?

This is my code:

```
...
     Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Photo");
        sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Photo");

        Uri foto = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/drawable/image"+subject);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, foto);
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, sendIntent, 0);
...
```

Comment: What is the error you  are getting?

Comment: try this one sendIntent.setType("image/*");

Comment: The error on Line is like: System error try again later...

Comment: "image/*" does not work either. But thanks for the suggestions!